# I to want introduce myself to learn new and advanced technologies like AI, blockchain

Tags: blockchain, tokens, bitcoin, cryptography

I have completed 2days blockchain executive program two weeks back. Course covers high-level concept on blockchain, ethereum

I have around 12+ yrs of IT experience and worked on different tools and technologies.

I want to introduce myself to learn new and advanced technologies like AI, blockchain. Please suggest how to start.

Regards
Amaresha Gante
+919740010891
coolamx@gmail.com